How to stop a function chain?
My project involves a chain of functions that basically loops.
startTurn() -> buttonclick -> checkWinner() -> startTurn().
If checkWinner sees that there is a winner it goes to victoryScreen(). The problem is that it immediately rushes through victoryScreen() and into startTurn(). How do I make it so that victoryScreen() ends the function chain.
button1.onclick = function() {
  chosen1 = basket[choice[0]];
  chose1 = basket.splice([choice[0]], 1);
  console.log(chosen1, turncount);
  giveColor(chosen1);
  checkWinner();
  startTurn();
}

function checkWinner() {
  let player1basket = sortBasket(basket1);
  let player2basket = sortBasket(basket2);
  let b1 = Object.values(player1basket);
  let b2 = Object.values(player2basket);
  let points = 0;
  if (turncount % 2 !=0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < b1.length; i++) {    
      if (b1[i] >= 3) {
        points++;
      } if (points >= 2) {
        victoryScreen()
      }
    } 
  } else if  (turncount % 2 == 0){
    for (let i = 0; i < b2.length; i++) {    
      if (b2[i] >= 3) {
        points++;
      } if (points >= 2) {
        victoryScreen()
      }
    }
  }
}

function victoryScreen() {
 button1.style.backgroundColor == white;
 button2.style.backgroundColor == white;
 button3.style.backgroundColor == white;
 button1.innerText == "Congrats";
 button2.innerText == "Player " + turncount;
 button3.innerText == "You're the Best";
  
 text.innerText = "Player " + turncount + " WINS!";
 return;
}


Please include startTurn too. Also, please clarify what you mean by "rushes through victoryScreen() into startTurn()". victoryScreen doesn't call startTurn().

And adding the relevant HTML in a runnable code snippet will help anyone troubleshoot and answer your question.

A function cannot force an exit of the parent function calling it. One option is you can just add a return statement after victoryScreen() to short circuit the loop. A better option is to sum the points, and then after the loop finishes, check if you need to call victoryScreen. An even better option is to make checkWinner return the winner or a boolean, and have a parent function use the result of checkWinner() to determine if you need to show the victory screen. That way the checkWinner function doesn't have to know or care about the victory screen.

When button1 is clicked, it will always check for a winner and immediately start a turn. At the moment, there is no logic stopping the turn from starting if there is a winner.
One solution would be to make checkWinner() return true if it finds a winner and false if it doesn't. Then you could use that to go to the victory screen if there is a winner or start a turn if no winner is found.
Here's an example of how you could change your code:
button1.onclick = function() {
  chosen1 = basket[choice[0]];
  chose1 = basket.splice([choice[0]], 1);
  console.log(chosen1, turncount);
  giveColor(chosen1);
  // Check if there is a winner and only start a turn if there isn't one.
  if(checkWinner()) {
   victoryScreen();
  } else {
   startTurn();
  }
}

function checkWinner() {
  let player1basket = sortBasket(basket1);
  let player2basket = sortBasket(basket2);
  let b1 = Object.values(player1basket);
  let b2 = Object.values(player2basket);
  let points = 0;
  if (turncount % 2 !=0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < b1.length; i++) {    
      if (b1[i] >= 3) {
        points++;
      } if (points >= 2) {
        // Return true here instead of immediately starting the victory screen.
        return true;
      }
    } 
  } else if  (turncount % 2 == 0){
    for (let i = 0; i < b2.length; i++) {    
      if (b2[i] >= 3) {
        points++;
      } if (points >= 2) {
        // Also return true here instead of immediately starting the victory screen.
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  // Return false since no winner was found.
  return false;
}

function victoryScreen() {
 button1.style.backgroundColor == white;
 button2.style.backgroundColor == white;
 button3.style.backgroundColor == white;
 button1.innerText == "Congrats";
 button2.innerText == "Player " + turncount;
 button3.innerText == "You're the Best";
  
 text.innerText = "Player " + turncount + " WINS!";
 return;
}


Thank you! It seems so obvious in hindsight.

I'm glad that my solution helped!
